# Time complexity of update and lookup in binary random access list

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, complexity

I'm trying to get through one of the exercises in Okasaki's "Purely Functional Data Structures," where he presents a zeroless binary numbers as a structure for random-access list, and asks to

> 9.6 Show that `lookup` and `update` on element *i* now run in *O(log i)* time.

"now" here contrasts zeroless representation with a plain binary tree backed random access list, for which the lookup and update time was estimated as *O(log n)*.

The approach in both cases similar: we maintain a Cons list of "digits", with every non-zero digit containing a tree of size corresponding to the digit's weight. The list as a whole is a binary (or a zeroless binary) representation of the number of elements in the list.

For example, a list of 6 elements, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` (binary for 6 is 111, zeroless binary is 22) will look as

```
[
  Zero,
  One(Node(Leaf(1), Leaf(2)),
  One(Node(Node(Leaf(3), Leaf(4)), Node(Leaf(5), Leaf(6))))
]
```

in binary, or

```
[
  Two(Leaf(1), Leaf(2)),
  Two(Node(Leaf(3), Leaf(4)), Node(Leaf(5), Leaf(6))
]
```

in zeroless binary representation. Now, the `lookup` and `update` times are defined by the time you spend locating the tree with the *i*-th element, and by the time you spend navigating that tree.

What I don't get is why loookup of *i* th element in a binary random access list takes *O(log n)* rather than *O(log i)*? We need to locate the tree containing the *i* th element — that's *O(log i)*, navigation within the tree is capped by *O(log w)*, where *w* is the size of the tree, which is clearly less than *i*2*.

What do I miss?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more detail on how the data structure works? I am having a difficult time visualizing it.

Comment: Added code examples; can add a proper description, but that'll render the question almost unreadable I'm afraid

Comment: I was actually thinking a _description_. Code is okay, but that is a bit much. How does the list differ from other types of lists? How does it use the tree? In plain English.

Comment: Well, as I was planning the better wording of the question, I came up with an answer; will it make sense to edit the question still — and answer it immediately — or is it better to just remove it?

Comment: I recommend updating the question and self-answering. I would be interested to hear about this different data structure.

Comment: Thank you for the help — I do appreciate it. The question is now edited, and the answer's given. Hope it'll help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, compliments to @snowman for the advice to rewrite the question in plain English — I came up with an answer while doing that.

The *O(log n)* boundary comes from the way binary numbers work: they have zeroes. For instance, a binary for 8 is 100, or, reversed, `001`. So the binary random access list of 8 elements (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`) will have the following structure:

```
[
  Zero,
  Zero,
  One(
    Node(
      Node(
        Node(Leaf(1), Leaf(2)),
        Node(Leaf(3), Leaf(4))
      ),
      Node(
        Node(Leaf(5), Leaf(6)),
        Node(Leaf(7), Leaf(8))
      )
    )
  )
]
```

Here, it's clear that any element will take exactly *2 log n* steps to get to (if you don't trust me on this one, play with *n = 2^k*, e.g. 256, 1024, 65536...). So the premise that "We need to locate the tree containing the i th element — that's *O(log i)*, navigation within the tree is capped by *O(log w)*, where *w* is the size of the tree, which is clearly less than *i*2*" was basically all wrong: the size of the tree does not depend on the element's index, and the position of the tree is dictated by the bits of *n*, not *i*.

In zeroless numbers, on contrary, we always have at least one tree of each possible size, so we can be sure that the tree will indeed be located in *O(log i)*, and its size will be not more than *2i*.